# Why auto drops the reference in return value?

Tags: c++, reference

If I make a method that return a reference to a member:

```cpp
class Foo {
    std::vector<int> data;

public:
    std::vector<int> &getData() {
        return data;
    }
};
```

And then use it to get my data:

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo f;
    auto myData = f.getData();
}
```

Why does myData is a `std::vector<int>` and not an `std::vector<int>&`? I am expecting to be able to modify the data from the outside so of course I want a reference. Should I explicitly declare `myData` as a `auto&`?

Also, in this case, should `getData` be declared as const? Because the method does not directly change the state of the object but could indirectly.

Comment: `auto` deduces the type, it doesn't know if you want a copy or a reference. You must use `auto &` if you want a reference. `getData()` should be declared as `const` if you don't want values to be changed, it would have to return `const` as well.

Comment: [Scott Meyers Usefull Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU).

Comment: Even if data is a `std::vector<int>`, it still a reference. The addresses are same for your 2 vectors.

Comment: @MatthieuH But if I don't use `auto&`, all the modification I make on `myData` doesn't hold on `Foo::data` so is there a copy that happens even if I return a `std::vector<int>&`?

Comment: @Jojolatino Holy sh*t, I didn't konw. Now I need to check all my code because I have lot of function which return reference and I often use `auto`.